# Upgrading I2C client drivers to the newer binding model

Tags: linux, drivers

I am trying to port some I2C device drivers I wrote for an other kernel to work with the newer I2C binding model. The kernel documentation goes through the steps of doing this: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/i2c/upgrading-clients

The thing that I don't understand is when using this new model, how does one specify the I2C address of the device? It used to be done like this:

```
static unsigned short normal_i2c[] = { 0x67, I2C_CLIENT_END };

I2C_CLIENT_INSMOD;
```

I don't think my bus/device supports detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up registering all my I2C devices as platform devices. The entry in the board file looked something like:

```
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata my_i2c_device = {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("my_i2c_device", 0x60)
};
```

(where I2C address = 0x60)

```
if (i2c_register_board_info(I2C_MY_BUS_ID, &my_i2c_device, 1) < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "i2c_init: cannot register my I2C device\n");
}
```

See http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt